# self promotion of an own code

Tags: discussion

Recently have make a post on [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation/188627#188627) which won a bounty. So I was thinking to make a git repository to put my code and even more documentation. Of course I'll put the link in my post.

First what about this "self-promotion" of my own code?

In the other hand when I saw this post: [Conditional compilation of code based on package version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191674/conditional-compilation-of-code-based-on-package-version) where the OP said:

> I am working on a document with a colleague and we have different
>   versions of PGF/Tikz installed -- I have version 3 and he has version
>   2.10. This is causing a problem for compilation on our two platforms because the syntax for defining matrices in tikz changed slightly from
>   version 2.1 to 3.0.

I was thinking to post a link to the first link I made which could also be considered as auto promotion and even more if I made a "real" project on git repository.

According to this post [about self promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263018/3559896), the link could be provide if it's a real answer not just a link. But for the second link the answer should be only: "you can use my tools using this link".

So the question is how should I deal with this if I make my project real?

Comment: IMHO: Anything helping others is great. Just explain yourself.

Comment: Linking within comments to other posts one has made is absolutely correct, there is nothing bad in it, as long you think your 'older' post will be helpful, but I would not post just an real **link-answer** in this case.

Comment: If your tool answers the OP's problem, I believe you can post a link to it, *with a detailed explanation of what it does and how it works*.  Alternatively, you can post the code as it currently is (if not too long) and add a link to the git repo saying that more up to date versions will be found there.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. So I'll know how to do when the case will be present (and when I'll make a good git repo `:-)`: A link to the code saying "it's a code I made which can help you because of this, that, .."

Comment: Thanks for asking, I actually have my own tool to throw into the ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb about self-promotion: if you link one or two times to something you did (or even are just a fan of), it's fine, but if *every post you make* contains a link to the same place, you're probably Doing It Wrong.

In your case, I don't see anything wrong with linking to this hypothetical project. Taking something that was already helpful and making it even better is always encouraged!

Comment: Was what I thinking due to all comment. I haven't take the time to make a github yet but thanks for your answer :)